Seeker or Value Bar Not Snapping?
I am currently working on a project for school and came across an issue. I am currently using Processing.exe for the project. The slider can't seem to snap. I tried following a similar question and its answer, but I still can't seem to make it work. The slider snaps to the value when I click the box where the arrow is placed, but if I press the arrow itself, it doesn't snap. It also seems that when it snaps, the slider isn't properly aligned with the guide. What am I doing wrong?
It's messy, but here is the code:
int x=75;
int lsW=17;
int lsH=50;
float bx =17;
float by = 25;
int boxSize = 50;
float xOffset = 0.0; 
float yOffset = 0.0;
float sbx = 483;
float sby = 25;
int sboxSize = 50;
float sxOffset = 0.0; 
float syOffset = 0.0;  

void setup() {
      size(550,300);
    }
void mousePressed() {
    if (mouseX > bx-boxSize && mouseX < bx+boxSize && 
        mouseY > by-boxSize && mouseY < by+boxSize) {  
        if (x > 75) {
            x = ((x+39 - 75) / 40) * 40 + 75;
            x -= 40;
        }
    }
    if (mouseX > sbx-sboxSize && mouseX < sbx+sboxSize && 
        mouseY > sby-sboxSize && mouseY < sby+sboxSize) {
        if (x < 475) {
            x = ((x - 75) / 40) * 40 + 75;
            x += 40;
        }
    }
}    
    void draw() {
      background(50);
      strokeWeight(0);
      fill (200);
      rect (75, 25, 400, 50);
      stroke(0);
  float value = map(x, 75, 475, 0, 100);      
      if(mousePressed) {
      if (mouseX >75 && mouseX <= 475)
        {x=mouseX;}
        }
      fill(0,255,255);
      rect (x, 20, 9, 60); 
      fill (255);
 
      // Left Button
      fill (200);
      rect (10, 25, 50, 50);
    {
      if (mousePressed == true) {
        if (mouseX <= 50 && (mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60)) {
        fill(255);
        if (x>100){
        x-=20;
      } else {
        x=75;
      }
      } else {
        fill(0);
      }
      }
      if (mousePressed == false) {
      fill (0);
      }
      triangle (50, 70, 50, 30, 15, 50);
    }
      
      // Right button
      fill (200);
      rect (490, 25, 50, 50);
      {
      if (mousePressed == true) {
        if (mouseX >= 500 && (mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60)) {
        fill(255);
        if (x<470){
          x+=20;
      } 
      else {
        x=470;
      }
        } else {
        fill(0);
      }
 }
      if (mousePressed == false) {
      fill (0);
      }
      triangle (500, 70, 500, 30, 535, 50);
    }
      println(x);
      {
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(255, 0 , 0);
      line (115, 60, 115, 85);
      line (155, 60, 155, 85);
      line (195, 60, 195, 85);
      line (235, 60, 235, 85);
      line (275, 60, 275, 85);
      line (315, 60, 315, 85);
      line (355, 60, 355, 85);
      line (395, 60, 395, 85);
      line (435, 60, 435, 85);
      }
    }


I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by "snap". The bar goes where the mouse clicks. Do you want it to automatically center itself on the closest tick mark? To help debug your code I suggest that you print out the 'value' at the same time you print 'x', ie println("x = ",x + " : " + "value = ",value); When x = 75 the value should be zero and when x = 475 the value should be 100.  There are several extraneous curly braces in draw().

i wanted it to stick to the closest tick mark when pressing the arrows or box, and then just freely adjust it using the seeker/slider. Your answer is perfect. Thank you!!

The following demo should be calibrated correctly; when the bar is centered over the tick marks, the values should be incremented by 10.  It should show a value of zero when the left arrow is long pressed and show a value of 100 when the right arrow is long pressed.  Clicks on the periphery of the arrows but still inside the  bounding rect will move the bar in increments of 10.  Redundant code was removed, and the tick mark code was changed to a 'for' loop for simplification.
int x = 75;

void setup() {
  size(550, 300);
}

void draw() {
  background(50);
  // Box
  stroke(0);
  fill (200);
  rect (75, 25, 400, 50);
  float value = map(x, 75, 475, 0, 100);
  if (mousePressed) {
    if (mouseX >75 && mouseX <= 475) {
      x = mouseX;
    }
  }
  // Bar
  fill(0, 255, 255);
  rect (x-5, 20, 10, 60); // To center bar
  fill (255);
  // Left Arrow
  fill (200);
  rect (10, 25, 50, 50);
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    if (mouseX >= 10 && mouseX <= 60 && mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60) {
      fill(255);
      if (x>100) {
        x-=20;
      } else {
        x=75;
      }
    } else {
      fill(0);
    }
  }
  if (mousePressed == false) {
    fill (0);
  }
  triangle (50, 70, 50, 30, 15, 50);
  // Right Arrow
  fill (200);
  rect (490, 25, 50, 50);
  if (mousePressed == true) {
    if (mouseX >= 490 && mouseX <= 540 && mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60) {
      fill(255);
      if (x<475) {
        x+=20;
      } else {
        x=475;
      }
    } else {
      fill(0);
    }
  }
  if (mousePressed == false) {
    fill (0);
  }
  triangle (500, 70, 500, 30, 535, 50);
  println("x = ", x + " : " + "value = ", value);
  // tick marks
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  for (int x= 1; x < 10; x++) {
    line(75 + 40*x, 60, 75 + 40*x, 85);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX >= 10 && mouseX <= 60 && mouseY >= 25 && mouseY <= 75) {
    if (x > 75) {
      x -= 40;
    }
    if(x < 75){
      x = 75;
    }
  }

  if (mouseX >= 490 && mouseX <= 540 && mouseY >= 25 && mouseY <= 75) {
    if (x < 475) {
      x += 40;
    }
    if(x > 475) {
      x = 475;
    }
  }
}


